# In an A/B test, how can you check if assignment to the various buckets was truly random?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, ab-test, runs

Trying to figure out how I can confirm that my A/B Test assignment is truly random. I know the runs test is used to test for randomness.

Is it possible to use the runs test to check if my A/B Test assignment is random?

Comment: Good question (+1). 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. True randomness is hard to ensure; even testing for random number generation itself for example is a very hard problem, let alone for something in a "real-life" setting. Nevertheless, we can make inroads following a bit of a causal analysis-informed framework. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no formal tests to determine if A/B test assignment to the various buckets was "truly random". What we can test is that we have achieved a balanced distribution against (most of) the key covariates behind our samples. That is for example we can use [$t$-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) or [$\chi^2$-tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) to check if continuous or categorical variables $X$ respectively have similar distributional characteristics to a certain extent. (e.g. the means of two groups being different in a statistically significant manner) Note here that there might be a [problem with multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) that we need to account for if we take this path.

The above being said, covariate balance in terms of feature $X$ sample is not why A/B tests work. Ultimately, A/B tests allow us to assume that: $(Y_i^A, Y_i^B) \perp  D_i|X_i$, i.e. that whether the $i$-th individual is treated ($B$) and untreated ($A$) is *exchangeable* in the sense that the assignment of treatment ($D$) depends only on the measured covariates ($X$) - this is known as the [*ignorability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorability). As such, the "no-unmeasured confounders" assumption (NUCA) holds and enables us to assume that any unmeasured confounders have cancelled each other out.

Bringing this all together now, a more aggressive way to check if the A/B test assignment was "truly random" would be to build a classifier $C$ that uses the features $X$ of our sample (e.g. user age, location, etc.) to predict if someone was assigned to the $A$ or the $B$ arm. If the classifier $C$'s performance is *very bad* (e.g. AUC-ROC < 0.55), then this means $C$ cannot make any meaningful distinctions between the two samples, and therefore we can say that our randomisation worked! This is very similar to what we do in [propensity score analysis](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/propensity-score-analysis) but without aiming to use $C$'s probabilistic scores further. (As for how to construct $C$: for starters, something simple (e.g. a random forest) should be good enough.)

Comment: Great perspective. Love the use of the classifier. Fascinating approach.

Comment: Great! I am happy I could help. In general, if you want to learn more about A/B tests having a small foray into the [Counterfactual theories around Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Counterfactual_theories) can be very helpful to contextualise things. If you find this answer useful, you can consider upvoting it, or if it answers your question accept it too.